# Is there a way to get more precise result when dividing Big Number?

Tags: javascript, npm, bignumber.js

I need to operate on Big Numbers but I need the results to be precise, like below:

```
const BN = require('bn.js');
var a = 11060622312717714974
var b = 1570481433500000000000;
console.log(a/b); //0.0070428227146040415
```

When I use Big Number I get only `0`, no precision:

```
var aBN = new BN('11060622312717714974');
var bBN = new BN('1570481433500000000000');
console.log(aBN.div(bBN).toString()); //0
```

Is it possible to get precise result with this library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not familiar with the library, but having a look at the `README.md` file, it says:

> Note: decimals are not supported in this library.

So, according to that, the answer would be no.

See https://github.com/indutny/bn.js/#usage.

Comment: Is there any chance this can be fixed by telling javascript (explicitly or implicitly) that we want our result to be of the built-in `Number` type rather than the no-decimals-for-you `BN` type?

Answer (score 0):

Precise is a funny word in computer science and JavaScript is not exception.

Notice the **input** compared to the **output** of this:

```js
console.log( 11060622312717714974 )
```

you don't always get what you want.

And there are situations like this:

```js
console.log( .1 + .2 );
console.log(  (.1 + .2) === .3 );
```

So, probably not what you wanted to hear, but knowing this up front you can **maybe** work around it.

Anyway, checkout https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/

Comment: @johnerfx A common workaround for this is to multiply your floating-point number (by 10^x where x is the number of digits after the decimal point), do the division, then divide (by 10^x) again to get your "precise" result.